# $X$ is locally connected iff every component of an open subspace of $X$ is open in $X$

Tags: general-topology

I'm having trouble understanding the $\implies$ direction, the proof of which goes like this:

Suppose $X$ is locally connected. Let $U\subseteq X$ be an open subspace of $X$ and let $U_0\subseteq X$ be a component of $U$. Let $x\in U_0$. Since $X$ is locally connected, there exists an open and connected neighborhood of $x$, denoted by $U_x\subseteq U$.

But $U_0\subseteq U$ is a component of $x$, so it must be the case that $U_x\subseteq U_0$. Hence $U_0$= the union of all $U_x$ such that $x\in U$, so $U_0$ is open in $X$.

I get that the union of all $U_x$ with $x\in X$ is a subset of $U_0$. But I can't convince myself that $U_0$ is a subset of the union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U_0\subset \cup_{x\in U_0} U_x$, since for every $x\in U_0, x\in U_x\subset \cup_{x\in U_0} U_x$.